# The value of . (dot) in the Maven Antrun plugin

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

In Ant, the `.` can be used to reference a base directory. I have a legacy project with one Ant file in the `/build` directory calling an Ant file in the `/src` directory (in this post I use `/`for relative directories to the project directory).

Now when I execute the Ant file in the `/build` directory, `.` is `/build` and when the process flows to the Ant file in `/src` the value of `.` in that file is `/src`.

Now I try to wrap the whole build in Maven. I put a pom.xml into the main directory and called the build file by

```
<ant antfile="cbuild.xml" dir="./build" target="all" />
```

In `cbuild.xml`, the value of `.` is `/build`, but in the build file in `/src`  the `.` now evaluates to `/build` as well.

How does this happen? Can I do anything about it?

Comment: Wrapping is a bad idea..better migrate the project ot Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise: The Ant build files of the project are maintained by a group in a different branch of our company. My task is to make every project compatible with Maven/Nexus. I try to migrate as much as possible to Maven, but if the Ant build is very complex and the responsible group has little time, we need to have an alternate solution.